# How to get the index of the recently selected item in a list box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox in which i have some items. I select some items in the listbox. The condition is that i want the selection to be continuous. If I select any other item in listbox which is not continuous with the selection,that item should be deselected immediately. I need to have the index of recently selected item which i tried to get with the help of SelectionChangedEvent but it gives me the index of first selected item. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the last item in the `SelectedIndices` collection.

Comment: This Deselects the item, if it is selected below the continuous selected group of items. If i select the item above this continuous group then it deselected this group. How do i know that i selected an item above or below the continuously selected items?

Comment: I need the index of the recently selected item in the listbox. I have a list box where i select items that are continuous. If i select item which is not continuous with the selection then it should be deselected automatically. I need to know that the item that i am selecting is below or above the group of continuously selected items. SelectedIndices count works well when i select an item which is below the continuous group, but not when i select an item above.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  You could keep track of what used to be selected and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the indicies of those continously selected items somewhere.

When any item is selected or unselected, catch this in SelectionChanged event. Check the SelectedIndicies collection, like SLaks suggested, to see if something except than your collection is selected, or if some of it's items were unselected. If you need, restore the presentation of listBox.